# How can I get element state from appendchild checkbox in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating checkboxes through appendchild.  I want to be able to check their state.  I know the format is supposed to be document.form.checkboxname.value but no matter what combination of form name or checkbox name I use it doesn't give me a response.

```
        var myParagraph=document.getElementById("myLine");
            myForm = document.createElement("FORM");
            myForm.setAttribute("name", "myForm2");
            mytable = document.createElement("TABLE");

        var CB_Delete = document.createElement('input');
            CB_Delete.type = "checkbox";
            CB_Delete.name = "CB_Test";
            CB_Delete.setAttribute("name", "CBTest2");
            CB_Delete.value = 2; 
            CB_Delete.onclick = answer;
            theCell.appendChild(CB_Delete);
```

To recap I want the answer function to give me an alert if the checkbox is checked or not.  Thank you so much!
To clarify what do I replace the form and checkbox with in the alert(document.form.checkbox.value)?

Comment: You're giving the checkbox different values to the attribute and property `name`. I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: Why does the checkbox get assigned a `.value`

Comment: @Matt Why would it be a problem?

Comment: I just hadn't seen that before, either that or I'm drawing a horrible, horrible blank.

Comment: @Matt Like any `input` element, a checkbox can have a `value` as well. When the form is submitted and the checkbox is checked, it will appear as `CBTest2=2`. The line `CB_Delete.name = "CB_Test";` seems to be unnecessary though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CB_Delete.checked` should work. See [HTMLInputElement on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement).

```
console.log(CB_Delete.checked);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xEtYj/)

---

- To make your checkbox checked or unchecked, you would do `CB_Delete.checked = true` or `CB_Delete.checked = false` respectively. `checked` is an object property that is expected to have Boolean values. `CB_Delete.checked` simply queries its current value.
- In your event handler function, you can reference the element that currently handles the event as `this`. So from the example in my previous jsFiddle:

  ```
  CB_Delete.onchange = function () {
      console.log(this.checked); /* this refers to the checkbox here */
  };
  ```

  You could use `this` in your `answer` function as well.
- You can read more about [handling events on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).
- **Note**: Using `CB_Delete.onchange` is a quite old and not really recommended way to attach event handlers most of the time. The use of [`CB_Delete.addEventListener('change', answer, false)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) is the right way to do this. Older IEs will have problem with it, but they have [`attachEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead. You can read about [this technique and why to use it on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) (the article is 3 years old, take this into account when reading things like `"Unfortunately few browsers support it at the moment."`). To hide the browser differences, you can use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: I must be missing something pretty fundamental here.  Thank you for your answer.
Won't CB_Delete.checked just make the checkbox checked?
and console.log(CB_Delete.checked); just tells me that CB_Delete is not a recognized object.
From the function seperate function "answer" what would I put in to get an alert telling me anything about the checkbox (function value etc)?  No matter what I try it can't seem to find the checkbox.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Zombian I will add some more details to my answer.

Comment: Wow thank you so much!  You solved my problem and gave me some good documentation.  I appreciate you going out of your way to add more and spend time doing this for me.